# Android Studio javah not a valid class name

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I was working on book "Chapter-3-Communicating-with-Native-Code-Using-JNI.pdf". There when I tried to create header files using javah command I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid class name: ?classpath
```

I tried the instruction in terminal:

```
javah –classpath bin/classes com.example.hellojni.HelloJni
```

But i see that this is for Eclipse paths and I am using Android Studio. So I tried this:

```
..helloJni\app>javah -d jni –classpath build\intermediates\classes\arm7\debug com.example.hellojni.HelloJni
```

I have HelloJni.class file in "helloJni\app\build\intermediates\classes\arm7\debug\com\example\hellojni". I am still getting the same error and I am surprised that I couldn't find a direct solution on stackoverflow. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy the `-classpath` argument from somewhere? Your error message indicates that `javah` thinks `-classpath` is the class name. And as it shows `?classpath` in the output, it seems the `-` is not what you think is, but some special character. Try typing `-classpath` yourself.

Edit: was curious. What you have instead of `-` is an &ndash;